# How do I get good quality photos onto an iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, photos

When I sync my photos with the iPod Touch, the photos are put on as very low quality.   They do not even look good at full screen size and do not cope with zooming in to see details.

I can't find a setting in iTunes to control how match it compresses the photos.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a re-sync if you recently updated to iOS 4.x

This resolved the issue for a user here:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=10844169&postcount=2

> this happened to me when I first upgraded my 3GS from 3.1.3 to 4.0, the moment the upgrade was complete, I unplugged my phone to browse the new features and I quickly noticed all my photos were low res, so I plugged my phone back to computer and hit sync, this time iTunes said "Optimizing Photos". Once that was complete, photos were back to normal.

Comment: we have done a few re-syncs and iTunes does say "Optimizing Photos".   It just seem to thing that saving space is worth more then having nice look photos you can zoom into.

Comment: Strange - it 'optimizes' my photos but I am able to zoom into them a bit once they are synced back to my iPhone.  Perhaps there is some issue with how they have been optimized - I don't think you can customize that.